# Добавление сеттера в производном интерфейсе или классе

Tags: c#, архитектура, наследование, интерфейс, setter

Имеется объекты со свойствами: `Id`, `Name`, `Value`.
Объекты могут быть разных типов:

- ReadOnly - все свойства доступны только для чтения;
- IdReadOnly - `Id` доступно только для чтения, свойства `Name` и `Value` для чтения и записи;
- NameReadOnly - `Name` доступно только для чтения, свойства `Id` и `Value` для чтения и записи;

Предполагалось создание интерфейса или класса с доступом ко всем свойствам только для чтения, а в производных интерфейсах или классах добавление нужным свойствам доступа на запись.

---

На данный момент делаю так:

```cs
public interface IProperty
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Value { get; }
}

public abstract class ReadOnlyPropertyBase
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }
}

public sealed class ReadOnlyProperty : ReadOnlyPropertyBase, IProperty { }

public sealed class IdReadOnlyProperty : ReadOnlyPropertyBase, IProperty
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public sealed class NameReadOnlyProperty : ReadOnlyPropertyBase, IProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

В принципе это работает.
Но как можно видеть выше, приходится в ручном режиме "синхронизировать" интерфейс `IProperty` и абстрактный класс.

---

Также имеется вот такой вариант:

```cs
public interface IProperty
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Value { get; }
}

public sealed class ReadOnlyProperty : IProperty
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }

    public ReadOnlyProperty(int id, string name, string value)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public sealed class IdReadOnlyProperty : IProperty
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public IdReadOnlyProperty(int id, string name, string value)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public sealed class NameReadOnlyProperty : IProperty
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public NameReadOnlyProperty(int id, string name, string value)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Но не знаю какими подводными камнями он обладает...

---

И ещё один...

```cs
public interface IProperty
{
    int Id { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string Value { get; }
}

public abstract class PropertyBase : IProperty
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }

    protected PropertyBase(int id, string name, string value)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public sealed class ReadOnlyProperty : PropertyBase
{
    public ReadOnlyProperty(int id, string name, string value) : base(id, name, value) { }
}

public sealed class IdReadOnlyProperty : PropertyBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public IdReadOnlyProperty(int id, string name, string value) : base(id, name, value) { }
}

public sealed class NameReadOnlyProperty : PropertyBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public NameReadOnlyProperty(int id, string name, string value) : base(id, name, value) { }
}
```

---

В связи с чем появились некоторые вопросы:

- какой из представленных вариантов правильный?
- каким образом принято решать подобные задачи?

---

P.S.: большое спасибо [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105)'у за помощь!

Comment: Информация для размышления: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791359/c-interface-inheritance-getters-setters

Comment: @defaultlocale Вы имеете ввиду, что нужно использовать new вместо сокрытия членов абстрактного класса? Какая между этим принципиальная разница в данном случае?

Comment: Нет, я имею ввиду что в том вопросе обсуждается похожая проблема и ответы могут быть полезны. Совет про new относится к интерфейсам, насчет того как его применить к классам нужно подумать.